# Real Life Scenarios to use ScriptEngineManager in Java

Tags: java, scriptengine

I am aware we can use ScriptEngineManager to execute scripts for example:  java script.

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String foo = "40+2";
    System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
    } 
}
```

But this is a very trivial example and I am not sure in what real scenarios ScriptEngineManager can be used? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to answer this from my project standpoint.
We have a framework that will make outbound calls and allow the integrators to extract the portions from json response and map it into internal data model.

This is completely driven by metadata, integrator uses  the jsonpath (similar to xpath but for json ) to specify what to extract and what to map it to.

But there are times, where the integrator want to specify some of these conditionally.
For example, if the json value extracted is null, I want model to have 0.
If the array length is 0, then i want to use certain value.

We have exposed these logic as javascript. We execute the javascript using this engine to find out what the inetgrator wanted to do with the data ( basically we execute the script provided by integrator on the data obtained and set that value on the model, which eventually gets persisted )

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible uses. For example: automation. The Microsoft Office programs and also Adobe Photoshop can run scripts to automatically execute functions of the program. You could use the Java script engine API for something similar in a Java application.

I used it once in a project where our software had to do some complex data processing. Certain parts of the processing could be customized by running a script. The advantage of this was that the script could be modified easily; if we would have written the custom processing in Java that would mean that every time when some small change was necessary, we would have to make a whole new build of the system.

Comment: I am still not satisfied with the answer. Java is very vast and can do everything what a javascript does and much more than that.. so why on earth I have to use ScriptManager? Is it used in some applications we use in day to day life?

Answer (score 0):

Going by the differences, Java is statically typed, implying, the program written in Java, is first compiled and then run but in case of dynamically typed languages, like JavaScript and Python, we can execute even a part of the program for it is not compiled as a whole as such.
Coming to the question, suppose you have a server(eg: WildFly) on which you have deployed your application. Now building and hosting is a time intensive process, thus if you have to make any small change, you'll have to rebuild it and then again go through that time consuming process but if you could have used any dynamically typed language like JavaScript in place of it, it would have taken no time and in the next implementation, you would have been ready with the updated code. That's the main advantage of using JS and thus ScriptEngine was added in JSR.

Currently I'm working with JBoss to add ScriptEngine functionality to their WildFly server so have been spending time with it in the real time.